# Having trouble updating my valid positions for a check function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[kingmovevalidity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqhAb.png)

[the function Im trying to add a check ability to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YeLb.png)

https://github.com/ryan-howard-hc/Chess/tree/main/reactchess

It holds the array of the valid moves of the piece that has already been moved. When you hit the easy mode button, it just shows the same places that piece was able to move previously. Ultimately im trying to have updatevalidmovepositions keep track of where the new piece's valid moves are so I can throw in a check function. Im new to this, so any advice is appreciated.

Comment: [Don't post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Take the time to type out or copy/paste the relevant sections of code and any errors as text in your question, preferably as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).